# Mongodb geo contains for polygon

Tags: mongodb, spatial

There is $geoWithin operator in mongodb. It selects documents with geospatial data that exists entirely within a specified shape. I need reverse function, that selects documents that contains my shape (it's parents).

Also I know about $geoIntersects operator, it returns not only parents, but children and intersections. But I need only polygons in that my polygon entirely included.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such operation in MongoDB. You can search for intersections and then check if any of them contains your shape.